# phpexcel thousand separator for xlsx

Tags: php, excel

I'm using

```
\PHPExcel_Shared_String::setThousandsSeparator(',');
```

to define a thousand separator for Excel file. Thanks to it, a cell is displayed as `55 452` instead of `55452`. Still, the cell value is an integer 55452, so it can be calculated, used within charts, etc.

Is there a similar way to define a million separator and so on (e.g. to define a separator each 3 digits)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define number format like this "#,#0.##;[Red]-#,#0.##"

```
$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer('example.xls');
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet("example_sheet_name");
$format =& $workbook->addFormat();
$format->setNumformat('#,#0.##;[Red]-#,#0.##');

$worksheet->writeNumber(1, 1, '100000',$format);

output : 100.000,00
```

Comment: Is that a PHPExcel example?

Answer (score 1):

A thousands separator will be used for millions, billions, etc; as far as I'm aware, Excel doesn't directly support different separators for each multiple

However, you could define a number format mask of:

```
#:###!###,##0.00
```

and it would probably work in MS Excel itself, though PHPExcel wouldn't format the value correctly

Comment: Can you please add a example with using PHPExcel_Shared_String::setThousandsSeparator? Thank you!

Comment: Does not work - formating above `#:###!###,##0.00` actually corrupts generated Excel document.

Comment: @lubosdz Then how would you do it in MS Excel?

Comment: @MarkBaker I used custom formating `#,##0;[Red]-#,##0`. For example: `$ws->getStyleByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0;[Red]-#,##0');`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood; I thought you had a way of defining a different millions separator to a thousands separator