# Set decimal separator to dot in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I need to have a dot as decimal seperator for my currency values.

Unfortunately in my excel file, I keep getting a comma instead. I can't figure out how to fix this.

I have tried several ways to format the cells thanks to a couple of other similar posts on here, but the output is the same.
I am using this now:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F1:F'.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');
```

I had found a variable that returned the decimal character, but I can't find that anymore, sorry. I have been looking for so long, that I can't find that specific post anymore. It returned a dot. That is why it is so strange that I keep getting a comma in the generated excel file.

Also tried to force the locale to en_us. Even though it should already be that.

Does anyone have any idea what else I could be checking?

Comment: What you see in MS Excel itself will depend on the locale settings of that copy of MS Excel, nothing to do with the file that you open. You can change them manually from within MS Excel (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e) but only temporarily

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot. I have now also figured out that in the example file that I received from our client, the numbers are actually strings. So that is why that file show the numbers with dots and my generated file shows the numbers actually as numbers, with comma's.

Comment: Check the below answer, It might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411265/phpexcel-thousand-separator-for-xlsx